# Timer fuera del UI

Tags: vb.net, vb

Estoy haciendo un timer que cree 1 hilo en cada tick sin importar si el anterior sigue ejecutandose, el problema de esto es que congela mi UI, sin embargo si hace los hilos correctamente.

En otro post explicaban que era porque el tick del timer se ejecuta dentro del UI y al crearse los hilos lo congela, entonces intento ejecutar todo fuera del UI, he probado con el backgroundworker pero se sigue congelando.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    hiloCertificador1 = New Thread(AddressOf crearObjeto1)
    hiloCertificador1.IsBackground = True
    hiloCertificador1.Start()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega-le un DoEvents() Para Que No Congele Tu UI...

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
   hiloCertificador1 = New Thread(AddressOf crearObjeto1)
   hiloCertificador1.IsBackground = True
   hiloCertificador1.Start()
   Application.DoEvents()
End Sub
```